# Wall Tiling Shower with Corner Drain

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, drain

I am preparing to start a bathroom renovation, and when we're redoing the shower, we plan to install a corner drain ([this one](http://www.signaturehardware.com/bathroom/drains-and-water-supplies/shower-drains/cohen-triangular-shower-drain.html), in fact). Based on the installation instructions, we need to angle the floor along both axes to provide about 1/2" of drop from the surrounding level floor.

How should I go about tiling the walls to accommodate the 1° slope? Are there fixtures designed for cutting small angles?

Comment: Tile saw is the best method to cut tile imo. Some of the big box stores rent them dirt cheap or even free when you purchase the tile from them. If you plan on other tile jobs in the future a small water cooled saw can also be purchased for under 100$, I have one that has lasted many years going slow and cleaning the water regularly they can last through many jobs.

Comment: I will use a tile saw, but I haven't seen any with small-angle mitering (like a proper miter saw might have). I am wondering about getting the angle I described on the lowest layer of wall tiles.

Comment: Mine has an adjustable push handle, I have to hold the tile tight and not push or the tile will shift but it works ok. Larger tiles are easier below 3" it gets really tough but I have done 1" on backing by making a holder to keep the tiles from shifting.

Comment: I plan to stick with large tiles (~12"), so that may help. At any rate, it sounds like making a small-angle fixture is the right way to do this. If it proves successful, I'll post it as an answer. Until then, please offer suggestions.

Comment: I also found that products like this one (https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Shower-System/Profiles/Schluter%C2%AE-SHOWERPROFILE-R/p/SHOWERPROFILE_R) exist, which allow for level tiling because they profile the drain slope. I will probably then fabricate a stainless template like that with a 1° slope.

Comment: Really cool drain but it may be advisable to spend more on the drain and less on a two axis slant. This drain: http://www.signaturehardware.com/carmen-linear-shower-drain.html is available in different widths and would allow you to just slant the floor in one axis making it easier to achieve your angle. I had a similar problem and came to the linear drain as a solution. Just a thought.

Comment: I thought about that as well. I just think for a corner shower (pentagonal shaped), having a side drain would be a little strange.

Comment: When you tile, start at the bottom drain corner on both walls. Work from there, therefore you would require less cuts. You could just do the wall first, full tile, then do your floor and slope it, eliminating the need to cut any tile.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but with waterproofing needing a continuous barrier, I didn't know if that was a viable solution. If you could post a detailed answer on that method, it'd help.